# decimal color conversion to rgb or hex color in three.js

Tags: three.js

i have a material color [65535] it should show yellow, but i get cyan color, what is the right way to convert this MsAccess color to rgb color in three.js.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how you would convert MsAccess colors programatically but looking at http://www.endprod.com/colors/ your color should be #FFFF00 or rgb(255,255,0);